# SEO for blogspot

Tags: seo, blogspot

I have started writing articles for my blog recently and then realized that google was not indexing it. So I went through some articles on google on how to do SEO. I have seen certain links suggesting meta tags are no longer useful to increase your rank.
From my experiments so far:
I have found, meta tags help for the keywords and nothing more.
Get more page hits and hence increased rank on the search engine by sharing on social networking sites like FB , twitter ,etc.

I would like to know what else can I do to increase. I know its not a one step solution or there is no readymade answer, but I would like to know what has worked for people on this forum :)

Another doubt I had is that google prefers original content as much as possible. I have posted some of my sport articles on my blog and on another website which publishes articles on the same sport but I have given a link to my original blog. But since the sports website has higher page ranking my page on the blog (the articles with same content) can no longer be found on google. Is there any way to stop it? Pls dont tell post on one location only. If there is a solution, I would appreciate that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are really important for SEO these days: fresh, original content (which you're handling with your blog!) and social signals. You should be promoting your blog on Google+, Facebook and Twitter, as well as participating in relevant communities.

You would be well served to become a regular visitor to a few niche blogs in your area of interest, and try to get some guest blogs posted. Blogs LOVE guest bloggers, and it's a great way to drive direct traffic back to your own blog, as well as increase your SERP placement for specific keywords in your author bio.

Participating in forums and other online discussions is a good way to work on driving traffic to your site. Create good, link-worthy content, and the SERPs will follow.